# Is it possible to add custom metadata for a file in google drive api v3 C#?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I have a list of files to be uploaded to Google Drive.

Is it possible to add custom metadata to each file?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.

See: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/properties

You can set `properties` and `appProperties` on the `File` object.

> "To add properties visible to all apps, use the `properties` field of `files` resource. To add properties restricted to your app, use the `appProperties` field on `files` resource."

Example (assuming you know how to upload the filestream with contenttype, and only want explanation on the metadata):

```
var file = new File
{
    Properties = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "CustomTag", "1234" }
    }
};
service.Files.Create(file, fileStream, contentType).Execute();
```

Comment: Thnks for the explanation. just last question how i can see this custom metadata in google Drive?

Comment: It looks like this isn't possible (yet). I found this post, which indicates it might be possible in the future. But for now it's in beta. https://support.google.com/a/answer/9292382?hl=en